# Optional Default Values

Tags: python

In python, is it possible to define overrideable, optional default values, where if you define the value, it doesn't use the default, but if you don't, it does?

For example:

```
def hats(a= 'large', b= 'baseball', c= 'five dollars'):
    #method stuff goes here
```

I know I could define `a`, and then `b` and `c` will default, but could I somehow just define `c` and have `a` and `b` use the defaults?

Like, could I call method `hats(NULL, something, something else)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> could I somehow just define c and have a and b use the defaults

Sure:

```
hats(c = 'something')
```

will use the default values for `a` and `b`.

Comment: We usually don't put the spaces around the `=` for keyword arguments, right?

Comment: Well, I know PEP8 does not recommend it, but I find it more readable, so that is what I do.

Answer (score 1):

Of Course. You can refer to the paramater name when you call the function

```
def hats(a= 'large', b= 'baseball', c= 'five dollars'):
        print a,b,c

hats(b = "football")
>>> large football five dollars
```

If you pass arguments but do not specify the names, the arguments will be passed in sequential order for example:

```
hats("big","tennis")
>>> big tennis five dollars
```

The above results in only changing the first two paramaters (a and b) and leaving c to the default value.

And lastly you do not have to pass any paramaters at all:

```
hats()
>>> large baseball five dollars
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the point of the default argument.  If you pass something in, what you passed in is used.  If you don't, the default value is used.